# Can I use VBA to update an email signature with leave dates?

Tags: vba, outlook

*I have been using VBA in Excel for about a year now, but I have never considered using it in Outlook.*

One of the email signatures that I use ends with "Advance notice of leave: [leave dates]", however I know that I will likely forget to update this after I return to the office. Is there a way to synchronise this email signature with my outlook calendar so that the signature will automatically update to show my next leave period?

If possible, please answer in simple terms because this is my first time coding with VBA in Outlook! Thanks

Comment: Do you have in your calendar „your next leave period”? Based on what to identify the code what are you referring to? If the signature is of html type, it can be edited and modified, but based on what?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model provides properties and methods for scanning the message body including the signature. The Outlook object model supports three main ways of dealing with the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately. For example:

   ```
    Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
      'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
      Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
      'Create e-mail item 
      Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
      With objMail 
       'Set body format to HTML 
       .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
       .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
       .Display 
      End With 
    End Sub
   ```
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.

After detecting the keyword in the message body you may create an appointment on the calendar, see [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) for more information.